# web hosting issue with one and one dot com

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I have a question regarding the webhosting in 1and1.com. I have hosted my website there, and installed myphpmyadmin. When I go to http://neopeutics.com/phpmyadmin/setup/, I keep having the problem Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in neopeutics\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177. Besides, I cant change permission for config.inc.php file for 777 in phpmyadmin. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Function is not installed. Talk to your host

Comment: I will refrain from remembering my experience with 1&1....  but they almost certainly have phpmyadmin available on their Linux servers accesable via some cpanel link. You should not need to install it. If they don't, find a new host.